# extract a column from a text file

Tags: python

I am trying to extract two columns from a text file here datapoint and index, and I want both of the columns to be written in a text file as a column. I made a small program that is somewhat doing what I want but its not working completely,

any suggestion on this please ?

My program is:

```
f = open ('infilename', 'r')

header1= f.readline()

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    j=float(columns[1])
    i=columns[3]
    print i, j

f.close()
```

it is also giving an error

```
j=float(columns[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Sample data:

```
datapoint                          index
66.199748     200      0.766113      0  1
66.295962     200      0.826375      1  0
66.295962     200      0.762582      1  1
66.318076     200      0.850936      2  0
66.318076     200      0.751474      2  1
66.479436     200      0.821261      3  0
66.479436     200      0.765673      3  1
66.460284     200      0.869779      4  0
66.460284     200      0.741051      4  1
66.551778     200      0.841143      5  0
66.551778     200      0.765198      5  1
66.303606     200      0.834398      6  0
.            .         .             .  . 
.            .         .             .  . 
.            .         .             .  . 
.            .         .             .  . 
69.284336     200      0.926158  19998  0
69.284336     200      0.872788  19998  1
69.403861     200      0.943316  19999  0
69.403861     200      0.884889  19999  1
```

Comment: use `numpy.loadtxt`. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: What exactly isn't working? I just ran it on your sample input and it worked fine, pulling the values (1/0) and 200.0 from each line. Now you want them written to another text file?

Comment: yes , but my program is running for lesser data, as my data points goes to around 20,000 indexes so its giving me the output but an error too which is j=float(columns[1])
IndexError: list index out of range   ,,,, and I want my results to be written in new text file ,,, I am writing the results with the following command python ./filenamre > out.txt

Comment: I know its working but I am asking for a good programming approach to solve this problem ...

Comment: The error is likely coming from a line that doesn't have the same input that you think it does; for which you could simply add a check

    `if len(columns) >= 2: 
        j = float(columns[1])`

Other than that, your approach is a fine way of handling this, so I don't really see the problem

Comment: I am really grateful for your comment, I have been searching for the solution for quite a long time , thank you very much ... but how to write my extracted coulmns in to new text file ?

Comment: What's wrong with redirecting through command line like you're doing? Or do you want it to happen within the script?

Comment: I want this to happen in a script ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will allow you do all of the file writing through Python. Redirecting through the command line like you were doing works fine, this will just be self contained instead.

```
f = open ('in.txt', 'r')
out = open("out.txt", "w")
header1= f.readline()

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    if len(columns) > 2:
        j=float(columns[1])
        i = columns[3]
    i=columns[3]
    out.write("%s %s\n" %(i, j))

f.close()
```

Warning: This will always overwrite "out.txt". If you would simply like to add to the end of it if it already exists, or create a new file if it doesn't, you can change the `"w"` to `"a"` when you open `out`.

Comment: Thank you very very much ,, yes its working like a charm now ... :) ...cheers ... have a really great day ...